# Testing Hapijs API with Lab

Tags: javascript, testing, hapi.js, hapi.js-lab

I'm getting started with Lab to test my API. The API does the usual CRUD operations and I'm wondering how should I go about testing the Update and Delete methods that require a document ID.

My API returns the newly created mongo document inside `response.payload`. What I don't understand is why in the `DELETE` test `resultId` is `undefined`.

Here's my code:

```
lab.experiment('User module', () => {

    var resultId; // Initialize a variable to save the document ID later.

    lab.test('should create user', (done) => {
        var options = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/api/v1/users',
            payload: {
                username: 'testUser',
                password: 'testPassword'
            }
        };

        server.inject(options, (response) => {
            resultId = response.payload._id; // Update resultId
            Code.expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(200);
            done();
        });
    });

    lab.test('should delete user', (done) => {
        var options = {
            method: 'DELETE',
            url: '/api/v1/users/' + resultId // Turns out resultId is undefined
        };

        server.inject(options, (response) => {
            Code.expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(200);
            done();
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're running lab with the `-p` flag, your two test cases will run in parallel. Which means the second test case is evaluating the value of `resultId` before it's changed by the first test case.

It's bad practice to have a test case rely on another test case changing some common variable. Your test cases should be totally independent from each other. Removing/adding a test case should never break another. This would be a real pain for maintenance.

Make your tests atomic and as separate as possible. Even if it means some repetition. Or you can use `lab.beforeEach` if you need to set up some common state before each test.

Comment: I'm not using the `-p` flag, but I see how having a test depend on the result of another is bad. Thanks for pointing that out.

However, how should I go about testing those endpoints that require a mongo document to exist?

Comment: You could mock your database object. Or use a test database with fixtures.

Comment: @MattHarrison just a simple example would be greatly appreciated :)